# NodeMCU resets in MQTT

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

Im sending GPS value over MQTT. after few sending the MQTT is falling to connect to MQTT server and it resets itself.

MQTT automatically disconnects and nodemcu resets with the following message.
MQTT failed with state -2

ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v951aeffa
~ld

Looking forward to a solution.

I used nodemcu lolin and for getting GPS I used 8m ublox m8n.

When is used to send normal string through MQTT it works perfectly but after sending GPS values through MQTT. MQTT fails in few seconds.

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>;


const char* ssid     = "test";
const char* password = "newagain";

const char* mqttServer = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
const int mqttPort = 2123;


WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

char MQTT_SERIAL_PUBLISH_CH[15]  = "stat" ;
char MQTT_SERIAL_SUB_CH[10]  = "bs1" ;


// GPS 
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
TinyGPSPlus gps;  // The TinyGPS++ object
SoftwareSerial ss(4, 5); // The serial connection to the GPS device
String GPSinfo = "HAI";


 void wifistart()
{
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

}


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
   ss.begin(9600);
  wifistart();
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
   reconnect1();
}

void loop() 
{
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
                   if (client.connected()) 
                   {
                    client.loop();
                    GPSS();
                   }
                   else if (!client.connected()) 
                   {
                    client.disconnect();
                    Serial.println("Forcing MQTT to connect");
                    reconnect1();
                   }
  }
  else
  {
    wifistart();
  }
//   delay(1000);
  }


    char * str1 ="HI";
void GPSS()
{

//  Serial.println("INSIDE GPS");
   while (ss.available() > 0)
   {
        if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
        {
              if (gps.location.isValid())
              {

                client.loop();
                 GPSinfo = String((gps.location.lat()),6) + String(",") + String((gps.location.lng()),6) + String(",") + String(gps.speed.kmph()) + String(",") + String(gps.altitude.feet()) + String(",") + String(gps.date.value()) ;

                        strtochar();
//                       GPSinfo.toCharArray(str1, 50 );
                        Serial.println(" ");
                        Serial.print(client.publish(MQTT_SERIAL_PUBLISH_CH, str1 ));
//                        Serial.println("delay Starts");
                        delay(1000);
//                        Serial.println("delay Ends");
                        if( client.publish(MQTT_SERIAL_PUBLISH_CH, str1 ) != 1)
                        {
                          reconnect1();
                        }

//                        Serial.print("Published DATA ");Serial.println(String(str1));
                        str1 ="0";
                        GPSinfo = "0";

              }
        }
   }
}



void strtochar()
{
   String s = GPSinfo ; 

    int n = s.length(); 

    char char_array[n + 1]; 

    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str()); 
  strcpy(str1, s.c_str()); 
}




void reconnect1()
{
  client.disconnect();
  delay(1000);
  client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");
 String clientId = "test";
      clientId += String(random(1,1100), HEX);
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) 
    {

      Serial.println("connected");  

    }
    else 
    { 
            if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
          {
            Serial.print("failed with state ");
            Serial.print(client.state());
              Serial.print("  ");
            Serial.println(client.connected());

          }
          else
          {
            wifistart();
          }

    }


  }

  client.publish(MQTT_SERIAL_PUBLISH_CH, "Started");
  client.subscribe(MQTT_SERIAL_SUB_CH);

}


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) 
{

  Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);

  Serial.print("Message:");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("-----------------------");

}
```

These are the output  i got while running the above code..

```
Connecting to WiFi..
Connected to the WiFi network
Connecting to MQTT...
connected

1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
1 
0Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419  //Im not printing this but some how its here.
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...
failed with state -2  0
.077691,76.989806,0.43,0.00,200419
Connecting to MQTT...

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>    

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffed40 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01b0


3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeea7c 40205c00  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v951aeffa
~ld
Connecting to WiFi..
Connecting to WiFi..
Connected to the WiFi network
Connecting to MQTT...
connected
```

Comment: So an unusual behavior followed by WDT reset. Sounds like stack(or heap) overflow.

Comment: On the first view into you snippet it seems that you call your functions massive recursively. First advice, clean your code to know what functions you have to call in what circumstances

Comment: @fisehara Thanks for the reply,

I want to send GPS values to MQTT server over 1-Seconds delay.
I had kept delay in the code and tried too after few MQTT publish the NODEMCU resets...

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: @BumsikKim I dint overload the stack too...